# How to subtract one csv value from another on bash?

Tags: bash, csv

I have two csv files: 
cs1.csv

```
total, , 1,2,3,4,5
```

and cs2.csv:

```
total, , 1,1,1,1,1
```

So im trying to subtract cs2.csv from cs1.csv, how would i do so?
Also should i turn the 'total' and blank variables to numbers to do so?

I have attempted to do:

```
paste c1.csv c2.csv | awk '{print $1 - $2 }' > result.csv
```

but the result turns up as 0.

**EDIT :** expected output should be:

```
total, , 0,1,2,3,4
```

or

```
, , 0,1,2,3,4
```

or so on...

Basically, the first two variables do not really matter as long as I get the numbers behind it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} NR==FNR{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) a[i]=$i; next} 
{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if ($i+0==$i) $i-=a[i]} 1' {cs2,cs1}.csv

total, ,0,1,2,3,4
```

`$i+0==$i` checks if a column value is numeric.

Comment: `{cs2,cs1}.csv` & `FS=OFS=","` Nice shorthands. ! :-)

Comment: Hmm, is there a good source for me to read up the methods you use? im quite new to bash script and would appreciate a good source so i can get better.

Comment: There are no shorcuts to learning `awk` or `sed`. Best start with a good tutorial [Awk Tutorial](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html)

Comment: Check [Effective AWK Programming](https://www.gnu.org/s/gawk/manual/gawk.pdf) or any other `awk` tutorial you can find on Google.

Answer (score 1):

If it really is as you show it, you can do it in straight `bash` if you are happier with a simple approach:

```
IFS=, read _ _ x1 x2 x3 x4 x5 < cs1.csv            # read cs1.csv ignoring first two values and using comma as IFS (input field separator)
IFS=, read _ _ y1 y2 y3 y4 y5 < cs2.csv            # read cs2.csv ignoring first two values and using comma as IFS (input field separator)

echo $((x1-y1)),$((x2-y2)),$((x3-y3)),$((x4-y4)),$((x5-y5))
```

**Sample Output**

```
0,1,2,3,4
```

I don't want to mislead you though, so you should be aware that `bash`cannot deal readily with floats/reals (non-integers) and this approach is not that flexible if the number of fields changes - but if you are learning, it may be good enough.

If you wanted to deal with real numbers, you could outsource the maths to `bc` by replacing the last line with:

```
bc <<< "$x1 - $y1; $x2 - $y2; $x3 - $y3; $x4 - $y4; $x5 - $y5"
```